# How to specify lib directory when installing development version R Packages from github repository

Tags: r, git, rstudio, devtools

In Ubuntu, I am installing all the R packages in the directory, `/usr/lib/R/site-library` by specifying `lib` option in `install.packages()`.

But when I try to install the development version of the R packages using, `install_github()`, it always installs in a local repository of the system user.

`.libPaths()` has 4 directories including the local repository. So, I have 2 questions,

1. Will it install in any of the other 3 repositories if i remove the local repository from `.libPaths()`?
2. Is there any way to specify installation library path in `install_github()`?

I am using `Ubuntu 12.04 64bit` and `R 3.0.1`

----------------------UPDATE--------------------------------

1. Unable to remove the local repository from `.libPaths()`
2. If I try to install using `install_github()` in **RStudio**, it installs in the `local repository` since `lib` is not specified.
3. If I try to install using `install_github()` as **non-root user**, it installs in the `local repository` since `lib` is not specified.
4. If I try to install using `install_github()` as **root user**, it installs in the `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library` since `lib` is not specified.

Is there any to specify `installation lib`?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

To add specified library paths in `devtools`, we need to use `with_libpaths()`

Arguments for `with_libpaths()` are, `with_libpaths(new, code)`

Following is an example for using `with_libpaths()`,

```
library(devtools)
with_libpaths(new = "/usr/lib/R/site-library/", install_github('rCharts', 'ramnathv'))
```

Courtesy: Hadley, [here](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/519) :)

And other than `with_libpaths()`, there are more options for in `devtools::with_something()`

```
in_dir: working directory
with_collate: collation order
with_envvar: environmental variables
with_libpaths: library paths, replacing current libpaths
with_lib: library paths, prepending to current libpaths
with_locale: any locale setting
with_options: options
with_path: PATH environment variable
with_par: graphics parameters
```

More explanations [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/devtools/docs/with_something)

Comment: `devtools::with_libpaths()` is deprecated.  Use `withr::with_libpaths()`.  See `help("devtools-deprecated")`.

Comment: This gives me `install: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/lib64/R/lib/libs3.so.2.0’: Permission denied
make[1]: *** [install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/tmp/RtmpShKPQi/devtools15aa419a91f09/AnalyticalFlavorSystems-RS3-536f287/src/libs3'
make: *** [libs3.so] Error 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RS3’
* removing ‘/home/hadoop/git/threat-odin/lib/R/RS3’
Error: Command failed (1)`

Comment: As indicated above (but not explicitly stated), the correct syntax is `withr::with_libpaths(new=libPath, devtools::install_github('<user>/<repo>') )`

Comment: This works now: `remotes::install_github("<user>/<repo>", lib="<path_library>")`.

Answer (score 13):

`install_github` takes a `...` argument that passes to `devtools::install`. `devtools::install` has an `args` argument.

> args
>   An optional character vector of additional command line arguments to be passed to R CMD install. This defaults to the value of the option "devtools.install.args".

`R CMD install` takes a library argument

```
 Options:
  -h, --help            print short help message and exit
  -v, --version         print INSTALL version info and exit
  -c, --clean           remove files created during installation
      --preclean        remove files created during a previous run
  -d, --debug           turn on debugging messages
                        and build a debug DLL
  -l, --library=LIB     install packages to library tree LIB
```

So the following should work:

```
devtools::install_github("repo", args = c('--library="./mypath/gdfgdg/"'))
```

however it doesnt appear to be replacing the call to `R CMD install`

```
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/bin/x64/R" --vanilla CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpucrXMD/RSelenium_1.3.2.tar.gz"  \
  --library="C:/Users/john/Documents/R/win-library/3.1" --install-tests  \
  --library="C:/Users/john/Desktop/"
```

Comment: @ManojG have you checked whether this works or not. It seems to work for me on my setup.

Comment: I tested out. I'm getting same kind of output as in ur answer. But still its not installing in the specified directory, but installs in local directory.

Comment: try `args = '-l "./mypath/gdfgdg/"'` and see if it makes any difference

Comment: This did not work, but the `with_libpaths()` answer did work for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a workaround, but I found a way using the command-line version of R.

Starting from Ubuntu:

`sudo -i R`

the trick (I found) is to use `-i` option

Then from R:

`.libPaths()`

my local R directory does not appear; the default directory is the one that I want.

Then, I `install.packages()` or `install_github()` with impunity.

Hope this helps,

Ian

Comment: @lanLyttle: Thank you. But it still removes only local directory from `.libPaths()` and not there are 3 more directories. Same as running R as root user.