# Install a github package alongside a CRAN package with the same name?

Tags: r, git, github, r-sf

Is there any reasonable way to install a CRAN package alongside a github package of the same name?

Specifically, I am after the `geom_sf()` geom in the `sf` branch in the `ggplot2` github page: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/tree/sf. So I can install the sf branch like this:

```
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2", ref = "sf")
```

And the CRAN version like this:

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
```

However, the `sf` branch is behind `ggplot2` in other useful features so I don't want to completely revert. So I am wondering what the best approach is here. Can I install both but somehow call one package ggplot2_sf? Basically I want to be able to use geom_sf with the all the functionality of ggplot2 that is currently on CRAN.

I had thought that maybe the best solution was to fork the ggplot2 repo, merged the master and sf branches then install that. But I am wondering if there is a better way?

### Update

So it turns out that you need to specify the lib directory using withr (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24646065/how-to-specify-lib-directory-when-installing-development-version-r-packages-from)). I tried this:

```
withr::with_libpaths(new = "./R/gh_libs/", install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2", ref = "sf"))
```

This returned this error:

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) :
>   Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)

So I can set the SSL certification to zero like this:

```
httr::set_config( httr::config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ) )
withr::with_libpaths(new = "./R/gh_libs/", install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2", ref = "sf"))
```

But then this doesn't install this in the directory I am after:

> Downloading GitHub repo tidyverse/ggplot2@sf from URL
>   https://api.github.com/repos/tidyverse/ggplot2/zipball/sf Installing
>   ggplot2 Installing 1 package: digest Warning in
>   utils::install.packages(pkgs, repos = repos, type = type, dependencies
>   = dependencies,  :   'lib = "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.3/library"' is not writable Error in utils::install.packages(pkgs, repos = repos,
>   type = type, dependencies = dependencies,  :    unable to install
>   packages

Any other ideas of what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: you can set the library location when you `install.packages` and also when you `library`, is that what you want?

Comment: Oh I see - so if I have my default library local for the CRAN ggplot installation then to install the ggplot2 sf branch on github I'd do something like this: `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2", ref = "sf", lib="./R/gh_libs")` the load it like this: `library(ggplot2, lib.loc = "./R/gh_libs")`? Am I understanding that right?

Comment: yep, I tried that on another package and kept both versions. there might be a cleaner way, not sure

Comment: See update for further attempts at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `devtools::dev_mode()` for this. From the man page:

> When activated, dev_mode creates a new library for storing installed packages. This new library is automatically created when dev_mode is activated if it does not already exist. This allows you to test development packages in a sandbox, without interfering with the other packages you have installed.