# New R-version installed - RDCOMClient not supported?

Tags: r, rdcomclient

Installed newer R-version 4.3.2, but now I can't install RDCOMClient-package:

```
install.packages("RDCOMClient")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘RDCOMClient’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
>
```

Is there any way to request an update from the creators?
Another source?

As a last resort, is there a substitute?
Thanks!

**UPDT1:**
Didn't know that, or had forgotten, in any ways - I get this error:

```
install.packages("RDCOMClient", repos = "http://www.omegahat.net/R", type = "win.binary")
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://www.omegahat.net/R/bin/windows/contrib/4.3:
  cannot open URL 'http://www.omegahat.net/R/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/PACKAGES'

   package ‘RDCOMClient’ is available as a source package but not as a binary

Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘RDCOMClient’ is not available as a binary package for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

Trying installation from github, as suggested from the other thread, also does not work for me:

```
library("devtools")
Loading required package: usethis
> install_github('omegahat/RDCOMClient')
Downloading GitHub repo omegahat/RDCOMClient@HEAD
── R CMD build ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✔  checking for file 'C:\Users\cfg010\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWeVLP3\remotes5bec30bc74ad\omegahat-RDCOMClient-c8f708a/DESCRIPTION'
─  preparing 'RDCOMClient':
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  cleaning src
   Warning in system2(command, args, stdout = NULL, stderr = NULL, ...) :
     'CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\rtools43\usr\bin\make.exe -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.2/share/make/clean.mk" -f Makevars.win clean'
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
─  building 'RDCOMClient_0.96-1.tar.gz'
   
'\\lvnuser.ad.lvn.se\cfg010$\Mina Dokument\R'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
* installing *source* package 'RDCOMClient' ...
** using staged installation
** libs
Error in system(paste(MAKE, p1(paste("-f", shQuote(makefiles))), "compilers"),  : 
  'CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\rtools43\usr\bin\make.exe -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.2/share/make/winshlib.mk" compilers'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.3.2/library/RDCOMClient'
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/cfg010/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpWeVLP3/file5bec77bf3e83/RDCOMClient_0.96-1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
>
```

**UPDT2:**
Running `devtools::find_rtools()` or `devtools::find_rtools(4.3)` both return `[1] TRUE` and `Found in Rtools 4.3 installation folder [1] TRUE` - so check on that I presume.

I assume you meant that `td <- tempfile()` should be `tf <- tempfile()`? If so running the entrie thing sadly does not work:

```
tf <- tempfile()
> dir.create(tf)
> withr::with_libpaths(new=tf,devtools::install_github("omegahat/RDCOMClient"))
Downloading GitHub repo omegahat/RDCOMClient@HEAD
── R CMD build ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✔  checking for file 'C:\Users\cfg010\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWeVLP3\remotes5bec59ec78c9\omegahat-RDCOMClient-c8f708a/DESCRIPTION'
─  preparing 'RDCOMClient': (354ms)
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  cleaning src
   Warning in system2(command, args, stdout = NULL, stderr = NULL, ...) :
     'CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\rtools43\usr\bin\make.exe -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.2/share/make/clean.mk" -f Makevars.win clean'
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
─  building 'RDCOMClient_0.96-1.tar.gz'
   
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/cfg010/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpWeVLP3/file5bec9d77a51’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
'\\lvnuser.ad.lvn.se\cfg010$\Mina Dokument\R'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
* installing *source* package 'RDCOMClient' ...
** using staged installation
** libs
Error in system(paste(MAKE, p1(paste("-f", shQuote(makefiles))), "compilers"),  : 
  'CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\rtools43\usr\bin\make.exe -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.2/share/make/winshlib.mk" compilers'
* removing 'C:/Users/cfg010/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpWeVLP3/file5bec9d77a51/RDCOMClient'
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/cfg010/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpWeVLP3/file5bec72a7255c/RDCOMClient_0.96-1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: `RDCOMClient` is not and never has been (afaict) on CRAN. To install it, per [its github repo](https://github.com/omegahat/RDCOMClient), you must use a custom `repos=` argument, ala `install.packages("RDCOMClient", repos = "http://www.omegahat.net/R", type = "win.binary")`.

Comment: Good point, apparently OmegaHat doesn't maintain their servers anymore? That's unfortunate. @jpsmith's link shows an option for installing using `devtools::install_github('omegahat/RDCOMClient')`, try that.

Comment: See https://github.com/omegahat/RDCOMClient/issues/49, they have not updated it for R-4.3.2.

Comment: I see - thanks, that's too bad. :( I tried finding last supported on the GitHub - but very new to GitHub - but I saw files were not newly updated so I was afraid of this... Not possible to install 4.2 for R 4.3.x?

Comment: The reference to `lvnuser.ad.lvn.se` suggests to me that something in your build cycle is working on a network path. This is often a problem with R on windows, don't do that. Install to a local directory and then copy over if needed. (I'm guessing the network drive is what you have in `.libPaths()[1]` or such.)

Comment: Packages built for 4.2 and 4.3 have some differences; I don't know enough about the internals to know what breaks, but the docs are clear that packages when upgrading to R-4.3, packages built for 4.2 will need to be recompiled (if needed) and/or reinstalled. Fix the network-path problem and I suspect you will be able to use `install_github(.)`.

Comment: You are correct @r2evans, this is an organizational computer, I don't even have Administrator-rights, ChatGPT suggest I try running R Studio from Admin-rights and try to install 'source package' - I'm gonna try that, but I need to call IT for that :@

To add to this RTools is 'packaged' for us and sent out remotely to the computer for installation, right now I have 4.3 and 4.2 - I suspect this might also be an issue - do you know any R-package that need RTools to install that I might try to confirm Rtools working?

Comment: (1) Try `devtools::find_rtools()` (in 4.3) to see if it finds what it needs. (2) Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/24668545/3358272 with a local directory for installing the package, something like: `td <- tempfile(); dir.create(tf); withr::with_libpaths(new=tf, devtools::install_github("omegahat/RDCOMClient"))`. If this succeeds, that means the problem _was_ the windows-network-drive thing, now you can copy the respective directory (nested) under `tf` into your real `.libPaths()` network location for more permanence.

Comment: I find chatgpt's recommendations on how to fix/install packages on R on windows to be ... not always consistent. I don't think "Admin" is going to work for you (though it is possible there is a permissions problem), but since network-drive-problems are a real thing, I suggest trying my other suggestion first.

Comment: I tried (1) - see "UPDT2" in original post. I'll try admin next.

Comment: Your installation is _still_ trying to use the network path, see `'\\lvnuser.ad.lvn.se\cfg010$\Mina Dokument\R'\n CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.` Change your working directory, it's not (only?) the `libpaths` issue. (Yes, `tf` not `td`, oops.) Try `withr::with_dir(tf, withr::with_libpaths(new=tf, devtools::install_github("omegahat/RDCOMClient")))`.

Comment: I do not concur why question was closed - the versions chg (thus the specific problems), and solutions in other thread does not work in this case. I have not tried Admin run or above solution. BUT a 'solution' of just copying the "RDCOMClient"-folder from "library" on another computer with it installed worked for me. As noted by @r2evans there is an open Issue on GitHub, and I have also e-mailed the author of pkg to cheer him up do maybe look at this.